# Find files in current directory, list differences from list within script

Tags: bash, list, content-management-system, find, hosting

I am attempting to find differences for a directory and a list of files located in the bash script, for portability.

For example, search a directory with phpBB installed. Compare recursive directory listing to list of core installation files (excluding themes, uploads, etc). Display additional and missing files.

Thus far, I have attempted using diff, comm, and tr with "argument too long" errors. This is likely due to the lists being a list of files it is attempting to compare the actual files rather than the lists themselves.

The file list in the script looks something like this (But I am willing to format differently):

```
./file.php
./file2.php
./dir/file.php
./dir/.file2.php
```

I am attempting to use one of the following to print the list:

```
find ./ -type f -printf "%P\n"
```

or

```
find ./ -type f -print
```

Then use any command you can think of to compare the results to the list of files inside the script.

The following are difficult to use as there are often 1000's of files to check and each version can change the listings and it is a pain to update a whole script every time there is a new release.

```
find . ! -wholename './file.php' ! -wholename './file2.php'
find . ! -name './file.php' ! -name './file2.php' 
find . ! -path './file.php' ! -path './file2.php'
```

With the lists being in different orders to accommodate any additional files, it can't be a straight comparison.

I'm just stumped. I greatly appreciate any advice or if I could be pointed in the right direction. Ask away for clarification!

Comment: Why are you doing this? What are you trying to solve with this list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-r` option of `diff` command, to recursively compare the contents of the two directories. This way you don't need all the file names on the command line; just the two top level directory names.

It will give you missing files, newly added files, and the difference of changed files. Many things can be controlled by different options.

If you mean you have a list of expected files somewhere, and only one directory to be compared against it, then you can try using the `tree` command. The list can be first created using the `tree` command, and then at the time of comparison you can run the `tree` command again on the directory, and compare it with the stored "expected output" using the `diff` command.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use coreutils? If so:

Put your list in a file, say list.txt, with one file path per line.

```
comm -23 <(find path/to/your/directory -type f | sort) \
         <(sort path/to/list.txt) \
         > diff.txt
```

diff.txt will have one line per file in `path/to/your/directory` that is not in your list.

If you care about files in your list that are not in `path/to/your/directory`, do `comm -13` with the same parameters.

Otherwise, you can also use [sd](https://github.com/MarianoGappa/sd) (stream diff), which doesn't require sorting nor process substitution and supports infinite streams, like so:

```
find path/to/your/directory -type f | sd 'cat path/to/list.txt' > diff.txt
```

And just invert the streams to get the second requirement, like so:

```
cat path/to/list.txt | sd 'find path/to/your/directory -type f' > diff.txt
```

Probably not that much of a benefit on this example other than succintness, but still consider it; in some cases you won't be able to use `comm` nor `grep -F` nor `diff`.

Here's a [blogpost](http://marianogappa.github.io/software/2016/07/30/diffing-streams-on-the-terminal/) I wrote about diffing streams on the terminal, which introduces sd.